# Markdown equivalent to LaTeX chapters and parts?

Tags: latex, markdown

I am thinking about the relationships between markdown and LaTeX, on of (among many) of the differences between the two is sectioning. Markdown uses hashtags as equivalents to HTML header tags, similarly LaTeX has `\section{}`, `\subsection{}`, etc. for sectioning. However, LaTeX also has `\chapter{}` and `\part{}`, but I can't think about what these would equate to in Markdown. Ideas?

One thought is to turn separate parts and chapters into separate Markdown documents, but that doesn't really feel right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[One of Markdown's design goals is to be very simple](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags.

Since LaTeX is more expressive than HTML, Markdown syntax corresponds to an even smaller subset of LaTeX than of HTML.

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself.

If you are targeting HTML, you should be looking for *HTML* that corresponds to a chapter or a part. One option is [the `<article>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article):

> The `<article>` HTML element represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be independently distributable or reusable (e.g., in syndication). Examples include: a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, or a blog entry, a product card, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

Another option is [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section):

> The `<section>` HTML element represents a generic standalone section of a document, which doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it. Sections should always have a heading, with very few exceptions.

If you are targeting LaTeX (or PDF via LaTeX) you'd want to similarly use LaTeX directly. Exactly how you do that depends on the tool you are using. Pandoc, for example, [supports raw LaTeX via the `raw_tex` extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_tex).